# Java - Why protected doesnt work on this function

Tags: java

```
package portale.interfaccia;
public class PageIndex extends FlowPanel {
    protected Integer prova;

    private PageCenter center;
    public PageIndex() {
        this.center=new PageCenter();
        this.add(center);    
    }
}

package portale.interfaccia;
public class PageCenter extends FlowPanel {
    public PageCenter() {
        super.prova=2;
    }
}
```

why, if prova is protected, i can't access to it by using super?
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PageCenter extends from FlowPanel, not from PageIndex. It looks like `FlowPanel` has no attribute named `prova`

If you want `PageCenter` to access a protected attribute from `PageIndex` using the `super` keyword, then you should extend from `PageIndex`.

```
public class PageCenter extends PageIndex{

   public PageCenter(){
      prova = 2;
   }
}
```

If you want both classes to extend from `FlowPanel`, try refactoring your code so that `PageIndex` and `PageCenter` know some utility class.

```
public class ProvaUtility{

    private Integer prova;

    public Integer getProva(){}

    public void setProva(Integer p){}
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
public class PageIndex extends FlowPanel{

    private ProvaUtility utility;

    private PageCenter center;

    public PageIndex(ProvaUtility pu){

        this.utility = pu;
        this.center = new PageCenter(pu);
        this.add(this.center);
    } 

    public Integer getProva(){
         return this.utility.getProva();
     }
}

 public class PageCenter extends FlowPanel{

    private ProvaUtility utility;

    public PageCenter(ProvaUtility u){
       this.utility = u;
       this.utility.setProva(2);
    }
 }
```

If passing this reference around doesn't make it for you, try using a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

```
class ProvaSingleton{

   private static ProvaSingleton instance = null;

   private Integer prova;

   private ProvaSingleton(){
      prova = 2;
   }

   public static ProvaSingleton getInstance(){

      if (instance == null){
          instance = new ProvaSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }

   public Integer getProva(){ return this.prova;}

   public void setProva(Integer p){this.prova = p;}
}
```

Then call it by:

`ProvaInstance.getInstance().getProva()`

Comment: uhm..but the protected attribute should show each variable in the same package no?

Comment: same package, as long as its an extension of the same object. PageCenter has absolutely nothing to do with PageIndex.

Comment: yeah, your solution works!!! only problem is that i need to pass every time the reference, and i have a lot of extension. Thanks man :)

Comment: But there is no way to put a variable shared for each class if it is in the same package?

Comment: @markzzz, no. Also to be more clear, protected will allow any class which extends it access to that member variable or method regardless of package. Specifying no access modifier is the only way to limit to package-private. The need to share some state within the JVM is often why people invent Singletons. Technically, a package-private static utility class could be used to dump values for sharing across multiple classes. However, that is a flawed global-state pattern that leads to untestable code and odd system errors.

Answer (score 1):

`super` in your `PageCenter` class is referring to `FlowPanel` because that is what it is extending.

`PageCenter` has no way of knowing that it is a member of `PageIndex` without a reference to that object.

I believe you are confusing inheritance and instance variables.

`protected` will allow access by the current class and any class that inherits from it.  It does not allow other classes in the same package to access it.

Comment: Arghhh...it's right, super refer to FlowPanel as superclass. Uhm...! So how can i share that variable for the whole package?

Comment: If you want a variable shared between classes, you must either inject an object containing it into all the objects that want to share it, or create a static variable with default protection and access that. (Remember - With statics, beware of the threads)

Comment: Uhm i don't have problem with concurrency. How can i access to a static variable?

Answer (score 0):

You must make PageCenter extend PageIndex.